# TIMESTAMP format conversion in python

Tags: python, string, list

How efficiently I can convert

```
date_format = "2019-01-30-10-07-50-000"
```

**Expected output**

"2019-01-30 10-07-50.000"

So far what I have tried :

```
ss = list(ss)
ss[10] = " "
ss[-4] = "."
print("".join(ss))
```

I Know i can do it using positional replacement using str replace() method,
IS there any other efficient pythonic way , both are timestamps

Comment: Your expected output refers to a different time from the input.

Comment: date_format you provided is "Unknown string format", When I tried to parse date from that string python throws an  "Unknown string format" error.

Comment: The way you tried is not a best way to solve it.Input string is an wrong format.The input is generated by system or you just provided as a input..?

Comment: Can I ask why you're not using standard ISO 8601 format for either input or output?

Answer (score 0):

```
date_format = "2019-01-30-10-07-50-000"
import datetime

d = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_format,"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-000")
print(d.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H-%M-%S.000"))
```